# Adding Maven Installation to EClipse

Tags: eclipse, macos, maven

I am following our wiki page and first we install Maven with HomeBrew and change the path to look like this:

```
Apache Maven 3.0.4 (r1232337; 2012-01-17 02:44:56-0600)
Maven home: /usr/local/Cellar/maven/3.0.4/libexec
```

Now it says do this:

> Add your maven home as a Maven installation (Eclipse -> Preferences ->
>   Maven -> Installations)

So here I am :

[image]

So I should add that Maven Home path posted above in here? But when I click on the Add... button it open a dialog to point it to some folder, but I can't navigate to that /usr folder at all. Can't find it.

Comment: It doesn't let you navigate your HD? In any case, I never install anything Java-ish via homebrew, I always just drop it in a directory--much easier, IMO.

Answer (score 0):

When you click add, you need to browse for your MAVEN_HOME folder of your external Maven installation. It sounds like your instructions assume you have already installed it outside of eclipse.

Comment: @Dave Newton Sometimes in eclipse, you can select the wrong option which only allows you to browse for folders/projects within your eclipse workspace.

Answer (score 0):

One solution is to ensure that your machine is visible in the Finder sidebar, as follows:

1. Open Finder Preferences
2. Go to the Sidebar tab
3. Look in the Devices section; the first item listed should be your Mac (mine is called "Andrew's Mac Pro" - make sure it's ticked.

Now when you click the "Add..." button in the dialog that you posted above, you'll be able to navigate to *your_machine_name*/*your_HDD*/usr/local/Cellar/maven/x.x.x/libexec and choose that directory. This just worked for me on OSX 10.8.3 with Eclipse Juno SR2.